# fix two bug in my python 3 program

Tags: python-3.x, function, sudo, su

My full source is here:

https://github.com/KiritoVsHalt/pyshell/blob/testing/pyshell.py

My qustion is how could I go about fixing these bugs? I'm still new to Python and I don't learn to well by just reading page after page.

1): grant() will only accept system commands not Pyshell commands(). This is because Pyshell can communicate with bash but bash can't communicate back.
grant() is calling sudo, but sudo can't call a Pyshell command. It's a one way conversation really.

grant() is on line 66
It depends on sudo.

2): When using admin(), if you CTRL-C instead of giving a password it throws errors and sometimes will not accept keyboard input until the terminal is restarted.

admin() is on line 63
It depends on su.

EDIT:

```
if OS == 'Linux':   
    def admin():        
        call('su')

    def grant(cmd):
        CMD = ['sudo',cmd]
            call(CMD)
```

Comment: post your code inline ..

Comment: actually never mind my question. i removed all platform-dependent "commands" from my shell. i'm going to reimplement them all in a platform-independent way later.(the whole "if windows, this; if linux, this; if mac, this" just takes up more space than necessary and is just really more work.) is there a way i can delete my question or mark it to be ignored or smething?